# several multlined equation alignment

Tags: align, subequations

I am writing something for a journal that requires two column page... space for equations is really small and some of my equation are fairly large.

When using the class of the journal equations do not fit, so I added some `multlined` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}[left = {\empheqlbrace\,}]
    &\begin{multlined}
    aaaaaaaa \\ 
    = bbbbbbb  \qquad \forall x \in \Omega, 
   \end{multlined} \\
  &\begin{multlined}
    ccc \\
    = ddd  \qquad \forall y \in \Gamma,  
   \end{multlined}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Questions,

1. Is there a better solution than `multlined`?
2. I would like to align the two `\forall`... any idea?

Edit: working example added.
PS: thanks for initial answers. New member here.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) as always on this site please provide a full minimal example that others can just copy and try out without having to add anything

Comment: Picking up on what @daleif rightly says, you might find this famous page helpful http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: In this case it is particularly important as `align` does not normally take any options in `[]`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{alignat=3}
       aaaaaaaa & = bbbbbbb &\qquad    \forall x & \in \Omega,\\
           ccc  & = ddd     &\qquad    \forall y & \in \Gamma,
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{alignat=3}
       \begin{multlined}aaaaaaaa \\
                        = bbbbbbb         
       \end{multlined}  &\qquad    \forall x & \in \Omega,\\
       \begin{multlined}ccc     \\
                        = ddd     
       \end{multlined}  &\qquad    \forall y & \in \Gamma,
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```